# Creating a capitalize Method in Dart

Tags: dart, capitalize

I am trying to create a method in dart but have run into a wall. I was looking at how .toUpperCase(); and .toLowerCase(); were done. The method that I am trying to create is .capitalize();

I would like to call this method like this
    String hello = "WORLD".capitalize(); //World

Here is the code I have so far

```
String capitalize() {
return this.codeUnitAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

When running String hello = "WORLD".capitalize(); I get the following error

> [38;5;124m[2015-6-4 11:37:13.011] Class 'String' has no instance method 'capitalize'.
>
> NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'capitalize'
>   
> Receiver: "WORLD"
>   
> Arguments: [][0m

I know i can call a function like `String capitalize(String s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);`
 But would much rather keep string Manipulation calls the same.

Thanks and I appreciate any help:)

Comment: You would need fot example extension methods to do this which Dart doesn't have (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot extend the String class like you want. Just use it like this:

```
capitalize("WORLD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not like JS, you can't just change any class in Dart. You can extend it only. E.g. you can create `MyString` class with `capitalize` method. But I don't think you want it. Just make some `StringUtils.dart` library with method `capitalize`

Comment: You can't extend basic types like `int`, `double`, `num`, `String` in Dart. `MyString` is probably not a good attempt (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Since dart is more common now, there are a lot more packages available at pub.dartlang.org.

I found a nice dart package for different operation on strings. It also contains a capitalize method.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/basic_utils

Simply add the dependency :

```
dependencies:
   basic_utils: ^1.0.3
```

Usage :

```
StringUtils.capitalize("helloworld"); // helloworld => Helloworld
```

It also contains other usefull methods :

- camelCaseToUpperUnderscore
- camelCaseToLowerUnderscore
- isAscii
- isNullOrEmpty ...

Answer (score 0):

if this is still a problem, you can simple use this dependecy:

```
dependencies:
  text_tools: ^0.0.2
```

Is simple to use, here is an example:

```
//This will put the first letter in UpperCase, will print 'Name'
      print(TextTools.toUppercaseFirstLetter(text: 'name'));
```